# Memoization fibonacci algorithm in python

Tags: python, algorithm, memoization

I have this memoization technique to reduce the number of calls getting a Fibonacci sequence number:

```
def fastFib(n, memo):
    global numCalls
    numCalls += 1
    print 'fib1 called with', n
    if not n in memo:
        memo[n] = fastFib(n-1, memo) + fastFib(n-2, memo)
        return memo[n]


def fib1(n):
    memo = {0:1, 1:1}
    return fastFib(n, memo)


numCalls = 0
n = 6
res = fib1(n)
print 'fib of', n,'=', res, 'numCalls = ', numCalls
```

But i am stuck at here: `memo[n] = fastFib(n-1, memo) + fastFib(n-2, memo)` and here `memo = {0:1, 1:1}`. How is it exactly reducing the number of calls each time i want to get fib of a number?

Comment: BTW - your memo should be: 
`memo = {0:0, 1:1}` 
and not
    `memo = {0:1, 1:1}` .

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should return `memo[n]` always, not only on unseccesful look up (last line of `fastFib()`):

```
def fastFib(n, memo):
    global numCalls
    numCalls += 1
    print 'fib1 called with', n
    if not n in memo:
        memo[n] = fastFib(n-1, memo) + fastFib(n-2, memo)
    #this should be outside of the if clause:
    return memo[n] #<<<<<< THIS
```

The number of calls is reduced this way, because for each value of `n` you actually compute and recurse from at most once, limitting the number of recursive calls to `O(n)` (upper bound of `2n` invokations), instead of recomputing the same values over and over again, effectively making exponential number of recursive calls.

A small example for fib(5), where each line is a recursive invokation:

Naive approach:

```
f(5) = 
f(4) + f(3) = 
f(3) + f(2) + f(3) =
f(2) + f(1) + f(2) + f(3) =
f(1) + f(0) + f(1) + f(2) + f(3) = (base clauses) = 
1 + f(0) + f(1) + f(2) + f(3) = 
2 + f(1) + f(2) + f(3) =
3 + f(2) + f(3) = 
3 + f(1) + f(0) + f(3) = 
3 + 1 + f(0) + f(3) = 
5 + f(3) = 
5 + f(2) + f(1)  =
5 + f(1) + f(0) + f(1) =
5 + 1 + f(0) + f(1) =
5 + 2 + f(1) =
8
```

Now, if you use memoization, you don't need to recalculate a lot of things (like `f(2)`, which was calculated 3 times) and you get:

```
f(5) = 
f(4) + f(3) = 
f(3) + f(2) + f(3) =
f(2) + f(1) + f(2) + f(3) =
f(1) + f(0) + f(1) + f(2) + f(3) = (base clauses) = 
1 + f(0) + f(1) + f(2) + f(3) = 
2 + f(1) + f(2) + f(3) =
3 + f(2) + f(3) =  {f(2) is already known}
3 + 2 + f(3) = {f(3) is already known}
5 + 3  = 
8
```

As you can see, the second is shorter than the first, and the bigger the number (`n`) becomes, the more significant this difference is.

Comment: Can you make a step by step explanation for the whole computation it does if you have enough time? Thanks

Comment: @MdSakib I just did, for f(5) example.

Comment: That's really great. I see how it reduces the redundant computation. Thank you

Answer (score 12):

It can be done with **functools** library in Python 3.2+

```
import functools

@functools.lru_cache(maxsize=None) #128 by default
def fib(num):
    if num < 2:
        return num
    else:
        return fib(num-1) + fib(num-2)
```

Answer (score 1):

It can be done within a single class or a function as follows

```
class Solution:
    def __init__(self):
        # initialize memo
        self.memo = {}


    def fib(self, n: int) -> int:
        # base case
        if n < 2:
            return n

        # check if fib(n) is already in memo - f(n) was calculated before
        if n in self.memo:
            return self.memo[n]
        else:
            f = self.fib(n - 1) + self.fib(n - 2)

        # store the value of fib(n) when calculated 
        self.memo[n] = f 
   
        return f
```

Answer (score 0):

The following method uses a minimal cache size (2 entries) while also providing O(n) asymptotics:

```
from itertools import islice
def fibs():
    a, b = 0, 1
    while True:
        yield a
        a, b = b, a + b

def fib(n):
    return next(islice(fibs(), n-1, None))
```

This implementation comes from the classic corecursive definition of fibonacci (a la Haskell's https://wiki.haskell.org/The_Fibonacci_sequence#Canonical_zipWith_implementation).

For a more direct (corecursive) translation see https://gist.github.com/3noch/7969f416d403ba3a54a788b113c204ce.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution without additional libraries or using a global variable:

```
def fib(n, memo):
    try:
        if memo[n]:
            # return memoized value
            return memo[n]
    except IndexError:
        pass

    if n == 1 or n == 2:
        # memoizing base cases
        result = 1
        memo.insert(0, 0)
        memo.insert(1, result)
        memo.insert(2, result)

    else:
        result = fib(n-1, memo) + fib(n-2, memo)
        memo.insert(n, result)

    return result

print(fib(8, []))
```